# Javascript stylistics - Professional looking code

Tags: javascript

I keep reading JS books that contain stuff like:

```
function onSuccess(entries) {
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML="";
    var ul = document.getElementById("file-listing");
    for(var index=0;index<entries.length;index++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = entries[index].name;
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

However, I read on multiple sites that it's faster and cleaner to create the whole list in a html = "", add the ul and li elements and then add the block, append it all in one call... so I am wondering if I should follow the style that I find in many js books or what I read on performance blogs? I am mostly concerned that people reading my code will find it amateurish, if I use the previous code block. Also I have meet a few people that are like, wow all you use is jQuery... instead of using DOM calls like `document.getElementById()`, etc...

Comment: Write it both ways, then test it, perhaps with [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/). But, even if one way's faster, it's likely to be only marginally faster and a micro-optimisation at best. So, regardless, I'd probably advise following what feels most comfortable to you.

Comment: Incidentally, an approximate comparison (tailor to your needs if it doesn't match your use-case closely enough) at the previously-mentioned [JS Perf: 'createElement or treat HTML as a string'](http://jsperf.com/createelement-or-treat-html-as-a-string). (Terrible title, I know, but it's all that came to mind.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What I am trying to do is to develop more quickly and clearly. I am working with very experienced web developers but my background is mostly native development in Java/C++. So I am trying to adjust, the work environment is very competitive and fast paced and not very question friendly. I am struggling to acquire the pace, so writing it twice is exactly what I am trying to avoid, and having my code constantly criticized is not something that I am used to. So and trying to acquire some stylistic knowledge fast, so I can be more knowledgeable when my code is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I read on multiple sites that it's faster and cleaner to create the whole list in a html = ""...

If you mean, `someElement.innerHTML = "HTML tags here";` then yes, it's faster in most cases, because fundamentally parsing and rendering HTML is *what browsers do* and so they're very fast at it, whereas if you build things up with DOM calls, there are lots of trips across various layers (JavaScript, DOM, browser internals) each time.

***But***: It also doesn't matter, in most cases. It can matter if you're rendering a 2,000-row table with lots of columns; but if you're not doing that it mostly doesn't matter. You can optimize if and when you see a problem.

> so I am wondering if I should follow the style that I find in many js books or what I read on performance blogs?

You should do whatever seems cleanest, clearest, and easiest to you.

> I am mostly concerned that people reading my code will find it amateurish, if I use the previous code block.

That's their problem. :-)

> Also I have meet a few people that are like, wow all you use is jQuery... instead of using DOM calls like document.getElementById(), etc...

There's nothing wrong with using jQuery for all or nearly all of your DOM manipulations; it's really good at it, and saves you a lot of time and trouble. You should be *familiar* with the DOM so you can use it when it's appropriate (jQuery doesn't do everything; in particular it's not good at dealing with text nodes), but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use jQuery when and where appropriate.

Toward that end, some reading:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

...but again, that doesn't mean you should use it just because someone looks down on using jQuery. Use tools appropriately. The important thing is understanding the tools you're using (including jQuery, and also the DOM itself), so you can understand when and where to apply them.

Comment: Surprise! You'r answer is not exactly correct nowadays. Chrome works with DOM methods faster.

Comment: @Oleg: That's interesting, do you have references and data to back that up? And of course, Chrome is only [15% of the market](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) (so far), and I did say "in most cases." ;-)

Comment: @Oleg: The [test case created by David Thomas](http://jsperf.com/createelement-or-treat-html-as-a-string/1) mentioned in his comment on the question seems to argue otherwise, as does [my update to it](http://jsperf.com/createelement-or-treat-html-as-a-string/2). The `createElement` / `appendChild` version tends to run about half as fast as the HTML string version(s).

Comment: Very interesting points. I am quite new to javascript, well not new, but recently I have moved to a more serious development since I am moving away from native mobile apps into web mobile apps (HTML5,CSS,JS) with native calls from PhoneGap, and other libraries. So I am faced working with people that have done web development for many years and have much more experience than I do in JS, it's a quirky language to tackle specially if like me you are used to Java, C++ as your development languages.

Comment: @AdamSurfari: It is indeed. It looks so much like Java and C++; but works very differently (it has closures, `this` is completely different, even familiar operators like `||` and `&&` work *slightly* differently). Definitely worth reading a good book (*JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by Flanagan is good), reading [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com) even if you end up disagreeing with him (as I do about half the time; the other half he's spot on), and you may find the [`javascript` tag on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript) useful. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the additional references, I will have to go thru them, unfortunately at this time I have a very tight deadline, I have two weeks to "translate" a order system from a desktop web app to a mobile app, using HTML5, CSS and Javascript. The good part is that most logic is done, but I have to implement the UI, rework the Form system for tablets and phones, implement Offline mode, Caching and Offline order sync and processing... I need to find some resources on working with mobile forms with JS for instance double tab to edit an order line, workflow improvement to data entry, etc...